# How do I construct a Salesforce Chatter FeedItem in Apex

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter, apex

How do I create a Chatter Post that looks like [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69226159@N07/10694237645/)?

What I want to do is, have a trigger that calls a function to create a chatter post when a new contact is created.  I want it to look like the image below.  Right now, I have a trigger on 'Contact' that calls a function, but I'm not sure of how to create a Chatter FeedItem that looks like this.

[Sample Chatter Post](http://www.flickr.com/photos/69226159@N07/10694237645/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an HTML-formatted chatter post.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hGNZAA2

Vote it up.

Comment: Thanks.  Still unclear of how to add HTML formatting to the chatter post, but you pointed me in the right direction.